# command execution on remote server shell

Tags: shell, ssh, remote-access

I am running a simple command on remote server using ssh on shell.

I am currently logged in `myHost01` and i'm running this command on `myHost02`

The expected result is `this is a test myHost02`. HOWEVER, I get `this is a test myHost01`

This is my command

```
sshpass -p root ssh -q root@127.0.0.2 "echo this is a test `hostname`"
```

I don't know why it is taking the hostname of the server I'm running the command from!!!

---

It is also noticeable that when I run this

```
sshpass -p root ssh -q root@127.0.0.2 "hostname"
```

I get `myHost02` (which is the correct output)

Comment: if you have a local $command variable containing what should be done remotely, just:  `ssh.....@... "${command}"`.  ex:  `command=hostname ; ssh ........@....  "${command}"` . Note however that it can easily get TRICKY... sometimes it's best to 1) create a local `the_script` script, and 2) `scp the_script  user@remotehost:/tmp/safe_name`  3) `ssh user@remotehost "/tmp/safe_name"` . safe_name being a name that is UNIQUE on the destination machine. Note that : someone else could replace safe_name (especially if within /tmp !). And many other potential security holes in those approach...

Answer (score 3):

Pass the command in single quotes, like below. The double quotes cause the shell to execute command substitution  `hostname` (locally) in-place and pass the resultant string `this is a test myHost01` to `ssh`

```
sshpass -p root ssh -q root@127.0.0.2 'echo this is a test `hostname`'
```

Comment: I just ran `sshpass -p root ssh -q root@127.0.0.2 'echo 'this is a test hostname''` But I still got the name of first host!!! 
(I put hostname between ``. I just ignored them in comments cuz I'd have too many of them and it'd be not readable)

Comment: @Matin, you should be having only one pair of single quotes there. Your command has two. Take a look at my sample command

Comment: Alright, but this command is an example. The real command is in a configuration file that the user will write.... The user can write any command. Nothing should stop him to put a single quote like that....

Is there a way to remove this limit??!!

Comment: @Matin, the fundamental point is this: if you need something to be protected from local command substitution, you need to enclose it in single quotes. In your example, offsetting single quotes protect the `echo ` bit and the the empty part ` ` at the end but the crucial piece in the middle `this is a test hostname` is missed!

Comment: Oh I see... Is there anything I can do about that? My line in the code is this. `sshpass -p root ssh -q root@127.0.0.2 ''$command''`
And here `$command` is set in a file by the user. He might as well put a command that has single quote!!! No solution to that ??????

Comment: @Matin: you should **NEVER** ssh a command to a remote host (especially as root!) that any user could create... But if you **really** want to and have good lawyers/backups/secondary job offers, just ensure that you retrieve the command within $command variable. Then you just:   `ssh .......@.... 'echo "this is a test: '"${command}"' ... end of test.'` : note that ${command} is within double quotes, so it will be replaced *locally* by the command. If command=hostname, you'll see `This is a test: hostname ... end of test.`. now you can `ssh ...@... "${command}"` : $command is done on REMOTE host

Comment: @OlivierDulac Thank you for the useful comment. I must do this though as I am asked by the supervisor. the REAL code is this `sshpass -p ${pass[$i]} ssh -q ${usr[$i]}@${ip[$i]} ''"${comm[$j]}"''`. Now `pass` and `usr` and `ip` and `comm` are arrays that are defined in a configuration file. Also `${comm[$j]} is equal to "echo 'this is a test hostname' > /home/eminmri/mymsg.txt"` Now mymsg.txt should contain `this is a test myHost02`. But it says `this is a test myHost01` ..... PS. `hostname` has `` around it. I just didn't put it here because of format purposes

Comment: @Matin: you are mixing level of calling. your comm[] should contain a COMMAND and its arguments, not a command + $(), which would happen on the local machine... I believe this comes because you really want to do a "echo test .... the_command" on the remote host, which complicates things further than they need to.

Comment: @Matin: in other words: have people place a `command arg1 arg2 ...` in their file. exemple: `hostname`. or `ls /`. Get those inside "comm[]" like you already do. And you, yourself, can then do a `ssh .... 'echo "this is a test: $('"$comm[$i]"') . End of test"'` (notice I place `$(` and `)` at the right place so they only get interpreted on the remote host, and I ended the  `'` around the `"$comm[$i"` so that this is done locally. And when happy, you `ssh .... "$comm[$i]"` directly. try it!